# Somebody named "Cohen" who is not a kohen: should he change his name?

Tags: names, kohen-priest, sheker-false

My question has to do with deception, and concerns whether or not a person needs to change his name. (I'm not thinking of a specific person, and don't require a psak).

For the sake of an argument, what happens if a man with the surname of Cohen marries a non-Jewish lady and has a son, who grows up and marries a *Jewish* lady, also having a boy. This boy is Jewish, since his mother is Jewish, and he has the surname of Cohen, since his father's surname is Cohen, but he is not himself a kohen since his father wasn't one.

In such a situation, would it be considered necessary for him to change his name, lest people mistake him or his subsequent male descendants for kohanim?

Comment: Anecdotally, I can say, I have known a few Cohens and Katzes (another _kohen_ name) who were not _kohanim_. And a Segal family that's not _l'viyim_.

Comment: @msh210 Were the Katzes in questions כץ or קץ? The latter is often shortened from Katzenelenbogen (or something like that).

Comment: @DoubleAA, כץ or even כ״ץ IIRC (but I'm not sure I do).

Comment: I am almost positive Judaism places some level of spiritual value on the name(s) that you are born with. I understand that in a practical sense, "Cohen" is used as a secular surname but nevertheless it is bersheit that the child was born with that name. Besides, changing his name implies that he has something to be embarrassed about, something to hide. It so happens I personally know a Levin who is not a Levite. He informs people that he cannot take the Levi's aliyah because he is not a Levi. People say, "Really? With a last name like Levin, I'm surprised!" And that ends it.

Comment: I know of a family which adopted the last name Katz during war times. So as not to be making a false claim, they spell their name like this: קטץ or maybe קאץ.

Comment: The last name is not of "Jewish" origin. A person is known by his first (and middle name(s)) and his father (occasionally g'father, and on rare occasions, great g'father's )names. So, if you're concerned about halachic ramifications such as being called first to Torah honors or *Birkat Kohanim*, you should be asking the person, directly, if he is a Cohen. And, if a person claims that he is Cohen when asked, we don't question his answer, unless we can prove otherwise. Many people have made errors in their lineage, and where possible (such as a pidyon haBen), we have ways to correct the error.

Comment: I'd like to get a better sense of your concern. Are you worried that keeping the last name may be a situation of violating *lifnei iver* (stumbling block before the blind)?

Comment: I once heard that the name Khan originates from people whose name were Cohen but were not Cohanim (although I know of at least one person named Khan who *is* a Cohen)

Comment: @DanF It seems more a question of _geneivas da'as_ than _lifnei iver_.

Comment: @Daniel Two counter-balancing issues - 1) We don't follow English last names. Thus, we should not assume that an English last name conveys any halachic meaning - certainly not as far as a Cohen status. Thus, when calling someone for an aliyah, we ask specifically of the person is a Cohen. 2) On the flip side, if a person says, "Yes I am a Cohen" we believe him, and we don't assume that he is lying, and that he knows. Sometimes people say that they are and eventually discover that they aren't. But that has nothing to do with the last name.

Comment: @DanF I'm not sure what point you're making. The name Cohen usually means the person is a kohein. Maybe a non-kohein with that name should change it so random people he meets don't give him undeserved honor (you can't expect him to explain his name to everyone he meets)

Comment: @Daniel The point I'm making is that I believe halachically, no assumptions halachically should be made from a last name in any language. I know that people tend to do this in the same way that people assume that someone with the l;ast name "Goldstein" is Jewish. But that assumption has no halachic binding basis AFAIK. Thus, I question that concept of *gneivat da'at* if it is founded on the person's non-halachic "thinking".

Comment: @DanF That's a novel approach. If you can support it, that would be an answer. But I don't think you're right.

Comment: @Daniel I'll see what I can find, b"n. This isn't a "popular" topic so it may be tricky. Shanah Tovah.

Comment: Interstingly we had three families in our shul named "Cohen". One was a kohen, one was a Levi, and one was a Yisrael. Since each was called to the torah properly (*ben ploni hakohen, ben ploni halevi, ben ploni*) there was no problem and no mistakes were ever made.